# Should you get paid more for using more languages?

Tags: professionalism, salary, career-development, careers, payscale

Let’s say a job requires C++ and Python on their description.

A few months later they give you a task that requires another programming language such as JavaScript.

Would this warrant asking for more pay since more languages/value is being used?

(Profession in Data Science/Engineering)

Thanks

Comment: Do you think that a person should get a raise for every incremental new skill they learn or acquire? Most people would say no.

Comment: Would you mind changing the title into "programming languages"? This site is not only for IT people and most people will think with "languages" about something like Estonian, Finnish, Norwegian etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If working in a different language adds to your workload, increases your responsibilities, or provides significant value to the company, then you should be asking for a pay rise.

**This is because your responsibilities and value you bring have increased, not because you're using a new tool.**

Even if you were hired as a specialist in a particular language, asking for work in another language is pretty common, and expected. Most contracts have a flexible clause saying that your responsibilities and duties can be changed within reason.

So if you're employed as a C++ programmer, asking you to do a task in JavaScript is considered reasonable, and doesn't really justify you getting paid more, unless it adds to your workload or brings more value to the company.

Comment: This answer seems extremely coherent and the first two sentences are completely clear - hard to see why anyone would downvote. Great advice here for the OP

Comment: I once read an internet meme that said "You are paid based on how hard you are to replace. Not on how hard you work". So I'd say the pay raise would depend on how hard it is to replace OP with someone with the same skills.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly if you're a **programmer** as such, nobody's going to pay you more for knowing more languages - you have to have mastered many and  master new ones that come along as a matter of course.

HOWEVER!  I notice you are a **Data Scientist**...

Indeed, I would possibly say that Data Scientists who know a bit of "more languages" are indeed more valuable.

You could *possibly* whine and make a case you have gone beyond your current pay, since you're a Data Scientist.  (If you were a programmer as such, the notion would be silly.)

So, - maybe! Good luck.

Comment: "Data scientist" is a term used very liberally, that could also mean a programmer who does mostly data wrangling as opposed to someone who does data analysis or builds models.

Comment: Hi @Peter , I've only ever hired say 4 "Data Scientists", so, your experience in doing so may be much greater than mine.

Comment: The problem is also that Data Scientists in many fields are paid a LOT more than the programmers. Domain experts being harder to replace and DS being the money maker.

Comment: @TomTom: That's... not true? Except maybe in finance or some niche fields. It's also not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Theoretically yes, may vary in practice

Every programming language you know is undoubtedly a skill. Of course, your proficiency in each skill could reach various levels (let's say from total beginner to master). But that is not the main question. Main question is **does your employer needs your skills ?**

I would give you one example: let's say you are working in a restaurant as a waiter. You are also reasonably proficient with C++ . But does this restaurant needs C++ ? Likely not. If you were skilled in cooking, you could occasionally double as restaurant chef, so you would have some ground to ask for a raise (otherwise restaurant could need to hire another person, which would cost more money then your raise) . But with C++ ... you would likely had to search for another employer to cash in that skill.

Now, in your case, you have been asked to do some coding in JavaScript which strictly speaking is not your job (especially as a data scientist) . But you have to ask yourself these questions: is this JS task so crucial for the company they would have to hire JS developer if you could not do it ? Is this task so hard that some of your colleagues could not learn some JS on the go and do it ? Does your employer really needs you in your primary role as a Data Scientist ?

With proper introspection you may find out that you were actually given some light JS coding just to keep you occupied and somewhat useful because you are not really shining as Data Scientist. Or you could find out that you are doing a tremendous job on both fronts and actually are exploited by the company. Depending on that, you may decide to ask for a raise, or to keep quiet and be thankful you have a job in a first place. In any case, what is important is to be true to yourself, and honestly assess the situation.